# Conectar Visual Studio ao banco de dados

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015, odbc

Olá, estou tentando conectar o meu projeto em Visual Basic, no Visual Studio, com o meu banco de dados MySQL, ele apresenta o erro abaixo, alguém saberia me dizer como resolver esse problema? Eu já instalei o odbc do mysql.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado
```

No meu código estou importando o ADODB. E estou fazendo a conexão da seguinte forma:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ODB = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties='DSN=fundacao;DESCRIPTION=fundacao;SERVER=localhost;UID=root;password=11111111;DATABASE=fundacao;PORT=3306'"
End Sub
```

E está dando erro nessa parte:

```
Sub busca_SQL(SQL)

    cox = New ADODB.Connection
    cox.Open(ODB)
    RX = New ADODB.Recordset
    ' MsgBox(SQL)
    '  Debug.Print SQL
    RX.Open(SQL, cox, , LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, -1) 'aqui coloca-se uma "SQL"

End Sub
```

Segue print:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu projeto é uma aplicação windows.

Comment: Bernardo, copie o erro e cole na pergunta junto com a parte do código que está causando o erro, a imagem fica muito difícil de analisar ainda mais se for pelo aplicativo do stackoverflow

Comment: Como está a configuração do teu odbc(odbcad)? Utilizas windows x64 ou x86? Tua aplicação roda como serviço ou como desktop? Vc colocou no ADO coretamente o nome da fonte ODBC?

Comment: Olá, estou usando sistema x64. Eu tenho um window aplication. eu configurei no administrador de ODBC do windows o mysql e a conexão de teste retorou sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema instalando o MySQL ODBC Conector de 32bit juntamente com o de 64 bits.